# How to access the first turtle of a code sequence in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I have the following doubts:
I have several individuals of 9 turtle codes.
The turtle codes are: R1M1 R2M1 R3M1 R1M2 R2M2 R3M2 R1M3 R2M3 R3M3. And I have 10 individuals of each code.
As the code is structured in a loop sequence and the order that the code exits in the result exported in .csv, I would like to ask the first individual of the first code (R1M1) to print the output header. But, I'm only getting it using one-of, and then the header often doesn't come out in the first line of the output. And I don't know how I can access the first turtle from the R1M1 code. Does anyone have any ideas?
What I thought of is calling turtle 0 which has the code R1M1. But, I still don't know how to do this in NetLogo.
OBS.: I tried to use only turtle 0, but in the other codes, too, there is turtle 0 and then the header appears.

Thanks in advance

```
      let n count turtles with [ profiles-code = "R1M1" ]
      if n > 0
      [
        ask one-of turtles with [ profiles-code = "R1M1" ]
        [
          prepare-header-output;; CALL A PROCEDURE
          
        ]
      ]
```

An example of how the header is coming out (has 3 individuals from each of the 9 codes)

[image]

Comment: Do you want one file for just R1M1? That is, do you want 9 files, one for each code?  Or do you want one file, with all the codes? Do you want the codes grouped?

Comment: Remember that one-of picks any one one AT RANDOM and might pick the same one twice or more. That's not what you want.

Remember that you don't have to do the counting and looping yourself. That is what  ASK does for you.

Do you really need the 'first' turtle to write the header? Just write the header.

Or do you want to pick one of the R1M1 and you want that turtle to start the report and make the others add to the report?

Comment: Hello TurtleZero, I want the output comes out all the codes. But, due to the structure of the code and some loops I can't just call the header in setup. If I do that, several headers in the .csv are output. So I thought that since the code list is sorted, I could call the header with the first turtle from the R1M1 code. But I still haven't succeeded. I edited the question showing an example output. If you can help me, I'll be grateful

Comment: I would like this: to pick one of the R1M1 (the first) and that turtle to start the report and make the others add to the report

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flag / semaphore variable to indicate if a header is needed. You'll need to adapt the below if you have your `turtles` outputting the data, but hopefully this will get you pointed in the right direction- more details in comments:

```
globals [ need-headers? ]

turtles-own [ class ]

to setup
  ca
  random-seed 1
  set need-headers? true
  if file-exists? "test_output.csv" [ file-delete "test_output.csv" ]
  crt 10 [ 
    set class item random 5 "ABCDE"  
  ] 
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  if count turtles < 1 [ stop ]
  ask turtles [ 
    if random-float 1 < 0.25 [ die ]
  ]
  
  ; Toy output example
  file-open "test_output.csv"
  foreach range length "ABCDE" [ i -> 
    ; Output headers if needed
    if need-headers? [
      file-print "turtle-type, count, ticks"  
      ; Change the need-headers? to false so this step will only happen once
      set need-headers? false
      
    ]
    let ltr item i "ABCDE"
    let n-type count turtles with [ class = ltr ]
    file-print ( word ltr "," n-type "," ticks )
  ]
  file-close
  tick
end
```

Output here looks something like:

[image]

but if I *don't* change `need-headers?` to `false`, it looks like:

[image]